# Show log level in Nginx logs

Tags: nginx, logging

This below is the django log entry,

```
INFO 2017-06-13 00:30:55,062 views 33096 140505817540352 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com
```

Here it is showing the log level `INFO` in the log entry.

Is there any way  I can show this log level in the nginx logs ?

Comment: See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) on `nginx` logging levels.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes I read that before, but that does not answer my question. How can I include them in my logs ?

Comment: Complicated but possible solution: Create an `error_log file [level];` for each log level with a specific file for these log levels, then from the most severe log level remove the duplicate logs in the file for the next less severe logs, then create a script that creates a single log file from the other log files (maybe nginx has hooks or something), in the combined log file you can prefix each line with the log level from the original log file name.